# Perform a join between the two tables to map country to each URL in table 1

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

[image]

Dear all,

Could you please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 1):

As of Oracle: one option might be to use `substr + instr` combination:

```
SQL> with
  2  -- Your sample data
  3  url (url) as
  4    (select 'www.amazon.com' from dual union all
  5     select 'www.amazon.ca'  from dual union all
  6     select 'www.amazon.uk'  from dual union all
  7     select 'www.amazon.in'  from dual
  8    ),
  9  country (suffix, country) as
 10    (select '.com', 'United States'  from dual union all
 11     select '.uk' , 'United Kingdom' from dual union all
 12     select '.in' , 'India'          from dual union all
 13     select '.ca' , 'Canada'         from dual
 14    )
 15  -- Query you need
 16  select u.url,
 17         c.country
 18  from url u join country c
 19    on substr(u.url, instr(u.url, '.', 1, 2)) = c.suffix;

URL            COUNTRY
-------------- --------------
www.amazon.com United States
www.amazon.uk  United Kingdom
www.amazon.in  India
www.amazon.ca  Canada

SQL>
```

Or, using regular expressions:

```
 <snip>
 15  -- Query you need
 16  select u.url,
 17         c.country
 18  from url u join country c
 19    on regexp_substr(u.url, '\w+$') = regexp_substr(c.suffix, '\w+$');

URL            COUNTRY
-------------- --------------
www.amazon.com United States
www.amazon.uk  United Kingdom
www.amazon.in  India
www.amazon.ca  Canada
```